# Python tkinter - failing to repetitively create text on canvas on loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The method bellow was meant to show the evolution of a backtracking solution of a sudoku on a canvas.

The *findAnswer()* function will return a 9x9 list with the original layout of the sudoku to *self.original* and a list of 9x9 lists to *self.btSolution*, which consist of all iterations of the backtracking solution.

The problem is that instead of showing all the iterations on the canvas, it just loops through everything and only shows the last one. I debugged and checked that *self.board.create_text()* is indeed being called every time with the right parameters, but only shows the numbers on the canvas on its last call.

```
def create_gif(self):
    self.original, self.btSolution = findAnswer(self.sudoku, gif=1)

    for sudoku in self.btSolution:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.board.delete("gifNumbers")

        for row in range(9):
            for col in range(9):

                if sudoku[row][col] != 0:
                    x = row * CELL + 0.5 * CELL
                    y = col * CELL + 0.5 * CELL

                    color = "red" if sudoku[row][col] == self.original[row][col] else "black" 

                    self.board.create_text(x, y, text=sudoku[row][col], fill=color, tags="gifNumbers")
```

Comment: Tkinter does not play nicely with `time.sleep`. Generally, Tkinter windows will not update with new content until your function finishes executing and control returns to the mainloop. So if you have a hundred items in `self.btSolution` and you sleep for 0.1 seconds in between each one, then the window will simply freeze completely for ten seconds, and then finally display whatever was last created. You need to use `root.after` or `root.after_idle` to get periodically updating behavior.

Comment: This describes perfectly what is going on. I will look into the suggested alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The same issue seem to be happening with `root.after`. Any new suggestion? Im calling the loop like this:

    `for sudoku in self.btSolution:
        root.after(100, self.plotBTSolution(sudoku))`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere in your "findAnswer" method you used some code like this:

```
new_answer = original # make a copy
```

And didn't realize that that code does not make a copy; it makes a new reference. To copy a 2D list you need the deepcopy function:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
new_answer = deepcopy(original) # make a copy
```